# Should we use the [rings-of-power]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Amazon Prime just released a new major show called **The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power**.

We already have [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power) as a tag, referring to the in-universe objects of the same name, with over 100 questions.

What tag should we use for questions about the new show? Should we remove the tag on the existing questions and only use it for the show? Can we use the same tag for both? Or should we perhaps make a new tag like [rings-of-power-2022](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power-2022)?

Comment: You have only one choice.  The Tag must be destroyed

Comment: @Valorum someone take it into Mordor quick

Comment: [tag:rings-of-power] is dead. Long live [tag:the-rings-of-power].

Answer (score 10):

Taking into account the following:

- There is a new TV show called *Rings of Power*, which people are probably going to ask a lot of questions about.
- There is an existing tag [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power), which is going to show up in the tag box when people start typing the name of the show.
- A specific group of magical objects in a specific universe don't really *need* a tag - we do have some such tags, but they're not vital to correct tagging.

I think we should **repurpose the existing tag name `rings-of-power` to be about the TV show**, otherwise we're going to be constantly retagging questions about it from new users. Even if we do create a new tag [rings-of-power-2022](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power-2022), people won't consistently use it. We're likely to get a lot of questions from people who aren't necessarily either hardcore Tolkien addicts or experienced SE users, but they just watched a new TV show and found a good site to ask about it. Let's make it easy for them to find the right tag. The magical objects don't need to have their own tag in future.

But, I hear you say, the existing [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power) tag has over 100 questions! Is this going to be a long process or require another big retag event? **No, manual retagging won't be necessary!** We can kill the existing tag by a single mod action, since it is (or should be!) always used together with the [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) tag. So I propose the following course of action:

1. Merge the current [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power) into the universe tag, which eliminates it from all questions without any manual editing.
2. Create a new `rings-of-power` tag for the TV show, and edit a few questions if necessary.

We should act quickly, though, before we start getting lots of questions about the new TV show. Thanks for bringing this to meta now rather than later.

Comment: Maybe the TV show will be so tightly written that it basically doesn't attract any questions.

Comment: I wouldn't hurry too much with such, a bit drastic, action. I your prediction comes true then it may be needed, but better wait for it.

Comment: @Mithoron Right now we don't have a tag for the TV show, so we need to decide what to do about this situation before people start asking many questions about that show. If the [tag:rings-of-power] tag continues getting used for both the objects and the show, then it's a mess which will need a lot of manual editing to sort out, which right now it doesn't.

Comment: This makes sense to me, and I feel the sooner it's done the better.

Comment: @Mithoron You wouldn't want to wait for too long, though, or you'll end up with a lot of TV-show questions that will get trashed by the tag merge and need to be sorted out manually.

Answer (score 5):

We should use [the-rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-rings-of-power).

Since the [full and official name of the TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings:_The_Rings_of_Power) is *The Lord of the Rings: **The** Rings of Power*, the tag should also have a "**the"** before "rings-of-power", just like [the-lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings) also has a "**the**" before "lord-of-the-rings".

As for [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power), [I agree with Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13769/7957), that it should be merged with [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium), removing the tag from questions not about the TV show, burninating its usage for questions about the magical objects. After merging, it should be repurposed and be made a synonym to the TV show tag, [the-rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-rings-of-power), for better tag searchability and to prevent users from using the [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power) for questions not about the TV show.

Comment: You don't need a synonym just for a missing "the". Typing "ringso" into the tagging field will already bring up `the-rings-of-power` anyway.

Comment: @TARS Not adding the synonym may cause users to tag questions about the magical objects with [[tag:rings-of-power]] again. We want to burninate the tag for such usage. In any case, adding the synonym won't hurt.

Comment: You need to be bloody oblivious to start typing that tag into the tag edit box without seeing the existing one pop up and clicking it, especially if you have more than 300 rep. But granted, users can be like that.

Comment: @TARS Not everyone is familiar with the tagging system. Adding the synonym does not have a downside. A non-new, >300 rep user actually just recently added [[tag:rings-of-power]] on a question about the TV show (and not the magical objects), even if [[tag:the-rings-of-power]] already existed, which proves my point on the synonymization.